# Does the Akka autopilot respond to messages that have already been sent

Tags: java, akka

When using the Akka `AutoPilot`, will it handle messages that were already sent to the test probe?

In particular, should I expect this code to pass?

```
new JavaTestKitDsl(...) {{
  TestProbe probe = new TestProbe(...);
  probe.testActor().tell("Hello", getRef());
  // Be certain that the message has been queued
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  probe.setAutoPilot(new TestActor.AutoPilot() {
    public TestActor.AutoPilot run(ActorRef sender, Object msg) {
      sender.tell(msg, null);
      return noAutoPilot();
    }
  });
  expectMsg("Hello");
}};
```

It seems that it fails as written, but passes if I move the `setAutoPilot` to before I send the message.

In the real system, the test is much more complicated, and I get to a point where three actors send different messages to the probe at the roughly the same time.  I had intended to set the auto pilot at that point, so that it was clear where I was expecting the messages to arrive, but it appears that I need to set up the autopilot before I send the messages that trigger the other actors.

The [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html#auto-pilot) does not say anything about this that I could find.

This is running with Akka 2.5.18 and Java 10 if that matters.